# Can a synthetic or bridge method be used to smooth an int -> double API change?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

Java has special markers on methods called `synthetic` and `bridge`.

> [JLS 13.1.7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/jls7.pdf), "Any constructs introduced by a Java compiler that do not have a corresponding
>   construct in the source code must be marked as **synthetic** ..."

So synthetic methods are anything generated by the compiler and not represented in the source code, and although it's not mentioned in that specification PDF very well, **bridge** methods are used to typecheck generics. (E.g. `Animal.interactWith(Creature c)` gets a bridge method `interactWith(Object c)`, which casts to Creature and calls the other method.)

---

We have this API called Bukkit, which provides stable access to change how a Minecraft server works. One facet of the underlying implementation of the API (aka vanilla Minecraft), which we have little control over, was recently forced in version `1.6.1` to change from integer values to float values. And in the interest of avoiding the difficulty of another change, we chose to change all our API methods to `double`s.

So, for example:

```
public int getHealth();
public void setHealth(int health);
// Must now be
public double getHealth();
public void setHealth(double health);
```

However, as always, we would like plugins compiled with the previous version, `1.5.2`, to still work as much as possible - that's the whole point of the API.

The `setHealth` is a solved problem, just introduce an overload.
And currently, we have a method named `_INVALID_getHealth(V)I` which is being renamed at implementation compile (*not* API compile) to `getHealth(V)I`, and this lets the old plugins continue to run.

However, when someone tries to extend our implementation of these renamed methods, they get compile errors from the doubly-named methods and overriding.

Is there a way to provide both the `int` and `double` returns using a **manually / tool-inserted** synthetic or bridge method, **that won't cause compilation errors** for those who try to change parts of our API implementation?

Comment: Why not name the method something different and just deprecate the original (or even leave it un-deprecated), and have it just return the double value rounded to int?

Comment: @increment1 I agree with you on how you should just change the name... I can't remember what Bukkit object it was, but I remember seeing methods like `_INVALID_setHealth(int i)` and `setHealth(double d)`

Comment: @Jojodmo I suppose i should write up an answer... (Affirmative, synthetic+bridge is what you need to compile a subclass)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is **yes** - if you mark a method with different return type but the same parameters as both synthetic and bridge, you can compile subclasses.

In this specific case, a new Maven utility, "Overmapper", was created to perform this task, though you could do it in any automated tool that can edit Java bytecode. Here's the configuration file:

```
members:
  "org/bukkit/entity/Damageable _INVALID_damage (I)V": damage
  "org/bukkit/entity/Damageable _INVALID_damage (ILorg/bukkit/entity/Entity;)V": damage
  "org/bukkit/entity/Damageable _INVALID_getHealth ()I": getHealth
  "org/bukkit/entity/Damageable _INVALID_setHealth (I)V": setHealth
  "org/bukkit/entity/Damageable _INVALID_getMaxHealth ()I": getMaxHealth
  "org/bukkit/entity/Damageable _INVALID_setMaxHealth (I)V": setMaxHealth
  "org/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity _INVALID_getLastDamage ()I": getLastDamage
  "org/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity _INVALID_setLastDamage (I)V": setLastDamage
  "org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityDamageEvent _INVALID_getDamage ()I": getDamage
  "org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityDamageEvent _INVALID_setDamage (I)V": setDamage
  "org/bukkit/event/vehicle/VehicleDamageEvent _INVALID_getDamage ()I": getDamage
  "org/bukkit/event/vehicle/VehicleDamageEvent _INVALID_setDamage (I)V": setDamage
  "org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityRegainHealthEvent _INVALID_getAmount ()I": getAmount
  "org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityRegainHealthEvent _INVALID_setAmount (I)V": setAmount
  "org/bukkit/entity/Minecart _INVALID_getDamage ()I": getDamage
  "org/bukkit/entity/Minecart _INVALID_setDamage (I)V": setDamage
  "org/bukkit/entity/Projectile _INVALID_getShooter ()Lorg/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity;": getShooter
  "org/bukkit/entity/Projectile _INVALID_setShooter (Lorg/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity;)V": setShooter
  "org/bukkit/Bukkit _INVALID_getOnlinePlayers ()[Lorg/bukkit/entity/Player;": getOnlinePlayers
  "org/bukkit/Server _INVALID_getOnlinePlayers ()[Lorg/bukkit/entity/Player;": getOnlinePlayers
flags:
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftLivingEntity getHealth ()I": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftEnderDragonPart getHealth ()I": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftLivingEntity getMaxHealth ()I": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftEnderDragonPart getMaxHealth ()I": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftLivingEntity setHealth (I)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftEnderDragonPart setHealth (I)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftLivingEntity setMaxHealth (I)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftEnderDragonPart setMaxHealth (I)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftLivingEntity damage (I)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftEnderDragonPart damage (I)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftLivingEntity damage (ILorg/bukkit/entity/Entity;)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftEnderDragonPart damage (ILorg/bukkit/entity/Entity;)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftLivingEntity getLastDamage ()I": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftLivingEntity setLastDamage (I)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftMinecart setDamage (I)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftMinecart getDamage ()I": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftProjectile getShooter ()Lorg/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity;": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftProjectile setShooter (Lorg/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity;)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftArrow getShooter ()Lorg/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity;": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftArrow setShooter (Lorg/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity;)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftFireball getShooter ()Lorg/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity;": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftFireball setShooter (Lorg/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity;)V": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftFish getShooter ()Lorg/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity;": 0x1001
  "org/bukkit/craftbukkit/v${minecraft_version}/entity/CraftFish setShooter (Lorg/bukkit/entity/LivingEntity;)V": 0x1001
```

You can see that all the int-returning methods are being changed to be flagged as bridge and synthetic.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do something with an entities health you can cast in to a `Damageable` and then there won't be an compilation error anymore.

```
Entity e = /* some entity */;
double health = ((Damageable) e).getHealth();
```

This should work.
I hope it helped

Comment: This question is from an API creation standpoint, not an API usage standpoint. Also, the plugin-developer fix is to put bukkit.jar higher on your dependency list.